# Using Electron showOpenDialog Filter allow to type user *.* which fails the filter

Tags: reactjs, electron

So i have used this showOpenDialog filter  for images(png,jpg,jpeg)working fine user can see only images extension.
but when Dialog opens user can type *.* and now  user can able to see all extensions which should not happen if i have given filter any suggestions?This is clearly a bug or there is any property from electron?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been working on an Electron project that imports files.

Here's how I was able to filter types:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(null, {
    filters: [ { name: 'Filetype', extensions: ['ext'] } ],
    properties: ['openFile'],
})
```

When using this method, I wasn't able to replicate your issue on Mac.